# How in Plone do we group users with different roles for same project

Tags: python, plone

My root folder is Project A, project B and so on ... I have 4 roles with different permissions. I create a project group_A with users belonging to different roles. How can I associate this group to the Project A folder, where each user will execute his own permission set related to his role? I can individually add the users, but this is not a good solution. ?I am using plone 4.1

I want to create a group of different users (with different roles) for each project. So I defined a custom workflow which has only 1 state i.e Private. Now each top level folder corresponds to a Project. Proj A, Proj B ...so on. Each user when logs in should be able to see only the folder associated to his project. This is possible when he has sharing permission for that folder. Now it happens that if he belongs to a project_a group (what permission should he have to access it if he is having a global reviewer role also for this project A). **How to define the permission for the group_a for this folder** for the other users with different roles?

Please check the diagram in the attached file. [image: Folder structure with users & groups]**Explanation** :- Project A , Project B are 2 folders in the home folder of the Plone site , each corresponding to a different Project. Project A has 6 users in a group called project_a group. Of these 2 users are contributors, 2 are reviewers, 1 editor and 1 reader. Each of these roles viz. contributor reviewer, editor and reader has different permission sets for the Project A only. Project A has a workflow with only 1 state - "Private". This will thus allow only group_a users to access the Project A folder contents, if it is shared with group_a. **Now each user having a different role in this group_a , should access the contents of folder A , with the permission set pertaining to his role only**. Question is : How should the permission be set for the group_a, in this case ?  Similarly group_b has users who can access contents of Folder B so that they get access to that folder only.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign local roles to both individual users and groups.

Let's assume you have a ProjectManager role, and a Participant role, then you can assign the ProjectManager role locally (a local role) to an individual user, and the Participant role to a whole group of users; each member of that group would have the Participant role within that location.

Comment: You are misunderstanding roles then; do not assign a global role to users or groups unless you want them to have the associated permissions globally too. That or I am misunderstanding your question; your terminology is rather muddled.

Comment: 'do not assign a global role to users or groups unless you want them to have the associated permissions globally too' - this means we cannot create project wise user groups with different roles ???

Comment: Sure you can, but assign roles locally. I sense a misunderstanding about what Roles, Groups and Permissions mean in Plone, but you haven't explained (in your question) what you are trying to do in enough detail.

Comment: @user956424: I'm very sorry, but I am having difficulty parsing your question, it is not at all clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: I think the diagram is quite clear and you can possibly provide some solution :)

Comment: Fixed it.I clearly understand we cannot create a group of users with different roles for a project. We can group users with same roles OR give permissions locally as @Martijn Pieters stated above.